# Rust AsMut copying rather than taking mutable reference?

Tags: rust, slice

My understanding of `AsMut` is that it is supposed to provide a generic way to take an argument which is "equivalent* to a mutable reference, i.e. it can be cheaply converted to a mutable reference.

However, I have encountered the following example code, I am trying to use `AsMut` just to be generic over `slice`, `arr` and `Vec`, but it seems to just be copying my array, rather than passing a mutable reference to it and modifying it in place:

```
    pub fn uses_asmut<T, M>(mut m: M)
    where M: AsMut<[T]> {
        m.as_mut().swap(0,1);
    }
    #[test]
    pub fn test_swap() {
        let arr = [1,2];
        uses_asmut(arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, [2,1]);
    }
```

(note, I know something must be wrong since I apparently pass ownership of `arr` to `uses_asmut` as an argument, but then the borrow checker doesn't complain on the next line when I use `arr` again!  If I change it to `uses_asmut(&mut arr)` the test passes, but I think the code as written shouldn't even compile!)

Comment: I think this is simply due to array implementing `Copy`, `uses_asmut(arr);` copies it when passed by value.

Comment: the `AsMut` bound in `uses_asmut()` allows you to call it with `arr` and `&mut arr`. If you call it with `arr`, you have to accept that the array will be moved (or copied) to the function. The fact that your `let arr = [1, 2]` doesn't even include `mut` is a giveaway that that array will not change. If your idea behind `AsMut` was to call `uses_asmut(arr)` and have it desugar to `uses_asumut(&mut arr)`, I don\'t think that's possible, Rust doesn't work like that. You'll have to make `&mut` explicit, or implement `uses_asmut()` as a macro.

Comment: Placing a trait bound on a function parameter restricts what types you can pass in. It doesn't change anything about these types, or how they behave.

Comment: Thanks @MartinGallagher I think this was my confusion.  I expected arr to be moved, but instead it was copied because array implements `Copy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The conversion** should be cheap. But you're passing the array by value, and that was never said to be cheap. You could pass `&mut arr` to not copy the array.

When we say the conversion should be cheap, we mean "don't do something like [`str::from_utf8_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8_mut.html)" that needs to scan the whole string. Indeed, the conversion from `[T; N]` to `[T]` is extremely cheap: so cheap, that it happens automatically by the compiler (coercion).

But it does not mean it is equivalent to mutable reference, because *it is not a mutable reference*. It is a generic type. If you want a mutable reference, take a mutable reference. You can even use `AsMut`, like `&mut impl AsMut<[T]>`.

There is no way `AsMut` could prevent you from moving (or copying) things but also not require you to type the `&mut` at the call site.

Comment: Suggest changing "moving" and "to not move" in the first paragraph to "copying" and "to not copy". Since the array is `Copy`, it is in fact _not_ moved (in the Rust sense) to the function, as evidenced by it remaining usable in the caller. Also, note that `&mut impl AsMut<[T]>` isn't really useful, as then the OP could just accept `&mut [T]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize array implements `Copy`.  I think `&mut impl AsMut<[T]>` is the right type here for accepting a mutable reference to something slice-like.

Comment: @user4815162342 I was not sure whether to write "copy" or "move" too, but decided to write "move" because it sounds more general (in essence, copying is moving without invalidating the original). And not any type that implements `&mut impl AsMut<[T]>` coerces to `&mut [T]`.

Comment: "Move" may sound more general, but it's not - move and copy are mutually exclusive in Rust. For exapmle, the book, when discussing copying, says that copied data [wasn't moved](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy). The more general term you're looking for is probably "passing by value".

Comment: @user4815162342 Fair, edited.